# Angularjs ui-grid how to display an image in a tooltip?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

Currently I can display an Image in a cell, I want to be able to display the full image when hovering over the cell.

I know you can give the tooltip a method such as

```
cellTooltip: function(row, col){

}
```

I have tried

```
cellTooltip: function(row, col){
    return '<img src=myimg/>'
}
```

but this simply displays the text, I want it to render the html

Answer (score 0):

Since ultimately the tooltip is just using the "title" attribute it can only be text as defined by the [spec](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp).

ui-Bootstrap has an "unsafe" tooltip that will show HTML.  tooltip-html-unsafe

Comment: I have tried something like <a tooltip-html-unsafe={{row.entity.preview}}> where preview is <img ng-src=imgurl>, but it does not work, am I on the right path though?

Comment: Try it using src= instead of ng-src .  It should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, for example 
`{ field: 'name', displayName: 'name', width: '7%', cellTemplate: "<div class='tblicon' style='text-align: center' ><img ng-src=\"../App_Themes/images/{{grid.getCellValue(row, col)}}.png\" title={{row.entity.name}} lazy-src></div>" }`

I hope it will work for you.